# How to replace words in excel file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, python-2.7

Is it possible to replace "firstword' with 'BBBBB' in all rows that contain 'firstword' ?
Please, what is wrong in my code ?
It would fiind the word I select from the most_occur1, and would print 'found it' as many times as this word is present (I use this just for test), but it would not replace it.

```
def finds_firts_word():



# find first word
    for cell in range(1, 2000):
        data = sheet.cell(row=cell, column=2).value
        if data is not None:
            data=data.lower()
            data_no_pct = data.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
            big_data1.append(data_no_pct)
    x1 = " ".join(big_data1)

    split_it1 = x1.split()

    Count1 = Counter(split_it1)

    most_occur1 = Count1.most_common(40)

    print(most_occur1)

    firstword = input('Please type word from list:  ')

    print('this is: ' + firstword)
    print('Replacing '+ firstword+' with bbbbbbb')
    REPLACE_TXTS = {
    firstword: 'BBBBBBBB',
    }

    for n in split_it1:
        if n == firstword:
            print('found it')
            for search_txt, replace_Txt in REPLACE_TXTS.items():
                x = str(split_it1)
                x.replace(search_txt, replace_Txt)







    print('done')
```

Comment: There is more than one wrong thing in your code. Please show us a little of your data so we can rewrite your code.

Comment: data is simple : Column 1(A) contains rows from 1 to 2000 with reference numbers(eq: x42421,etc) and column 2(B) contains rows from 1 to 2000 with item names (different titles). I know I'm a noob and this code is all over the place (I'm new to py), but it does what I need it to do, just this replace part it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing I see here is that you're splitting the text, then replacing things in the list of split texts, which won't affect the original one.

Like, this:

```
text = "one, two, three, four, things"
for x in text.split(", "):
    x.replace("o", "q")
```

won't change the variable `text`. It just changes the elements in the list `["one", "two", "three", "four", "things"]` that was generated to be used within the `for`.

Not sure if that alone is enough to point you to the right direction.

One workaround would be:

```
text = "one, two, three, four, things"

new_text = []
for x in text.split(", "):
    x.replace("o", "q")
    new_text.append(x)

text = ", ".join(new_text)
```

Then you'd have `"qne, twq, three, fqur, things"` in the end.

Comment: Have tried this, but it would not modify anything in my excel file

Comment: I still think it's because you're not writing the altered things back into the file. I'm not sure what's the proper way of writing into excel files though, cause I've never worked with those. But I'm quite sure that the issue is you're just changing the copied version (the text you got from the excel file) instead of the original file itself.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code helps you:

```
from typing import Counter
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_excel (r'yourexcelfilename.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', header=None)

most_occur = Counter(df[1]).most_common(40)

print (most_occur)

firstword = input('Please type word from list:  ')
print('this is: ' + firstword)
print('Replacing '+ firstword+' with bbbbbbb')

for row in df[1].index:
    df.loc[row, 1] = re.sub(firstword,"bbbbbbb", df.loc[row,1] )
print(df)
```

with `regex` it doesn't matter what is in column B. You can replace `firstword` with anything anywhere.

Comment: Hi, Thank you . This will not work mainly because the code I use takes each cell from range 1-2000 and splits words inside one cell (values from B cells contain Names made out of multiple words). This sugestion  counts  complete cell

Comment: If the only issue with this answer is that ```df.loc[name][1]``` is a whole cell (...but you need to replace words inside of it), you can try this ```df.loc[name, 1] = " ".join([“bbbbbbb” if word == firstword else word for word in df.loc[name][1].split()])``` instead of the two lines that you had inside the for loop (I'm guessing your words in the cell are separated by spaces).

Comment: @madacmjtr in the for loop number of data is not an issue. If you wanna iterate in a specific number of data then modified the code as you wish.  I change the code a little bit, check it out